# Standalone Next.js server returns 404 for static content unless next start is called at least once

Tags: node.js, next.js, pnpm

I'm trying to deploy the following project to production: https://github.com/saleor/apps
The submodule in question: https://github.com/saleor/apps/tree/main/apps/slack

Here are the steps I'm taking.

- cd /apps/slack
- pnpm install
- pmpm build (this runs graphql-codegen && next build)

I have set `output: "standalone"` in my next.config.js

The problem is when I try to run the standalone server using:

```
node .next/standalone/apps/slack/server.js
```

I get 404s:
[image: 404s in chrome inspector]

Until I do:

- pnpm start (runs next start)
- Open a browser and go to `localhost:3000`
- Kill pnpm start

Then the 404s go away... even when running `node .next/standalone/apps/slack/server.js`
[image]

I'm asking because this seems to be related to Next.js not to the app itself? But I'm not experienced with Next.js or Node development so I'm not sure.

This is a problem for me because I want to make a docker image. And I'm having issues translating this workflow into a Dockerfile.

Edit:

I tried using the Dockerfile from https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker
However they don't include `start` in the build process.

Edit 2:

By running `diff -qr working/ broken/` I found no differences after running `pnpm start`.
Can this be caused by Chrome caching?

Edit 3:

It appears to be a caching issue, as after running pnpm start and accessing the page from chrome the issue persists in Firefox when using the standalone server.js
However I have no idea why the page loads when using `next start` and not `node server.js`

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a pnpm monorepo, when using Next.js standalone output you have to manually copy the static and public folders.

> Additionally, a minimal server.js file is also output which can be used instead of next start. This minimal server does not copy the public or .next/static folders by default as these should ideally be handled by a CDN instead, although these folders can be copied to the standalone/public and standalone/.next/static folders manually, after which server.js file will serve these automatically.

However I was copying them to the wrong destination, causing the 404s.

Copy to `standalone/apps/slack/.next` instead of `standalone/.next`, same thing for public.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/output#automatically-copying-traced-files